# What does argument args.length mean?

Tags: java, args

I would like to ask you about help explaining args.length !=2 in program below. In book I read they check whether there are two files but why using ! exclamation point? It doesn´t make sence for me. I have found info about args.length but not about this checking file even on stackowerflow and from this reason I am asking here. Thank you.

```
java CopyFile first.txt second.txt - this is put on comand line

import java.io.*;

class CopyFile{
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

    int i;

      FileInputStream fileIn = null;
      FileOutputStream fileOut = null;

        **//firstly check whether both two files has been set up**
        if(args.length != 2) {
          System.out.println("Using: CopyFile system");
          return;
        }
```

Comment: `!=` means "not equal to" in Java (and several other languages). I'd recommending reading up on the basic language syntax, see e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html for the various operators.

Comment: The logic is looking for exactly two arguments on the command line. If there aren't exactly two arguments, the program prints that little message and returns

Comment: Thanks nicomp now it makes me a sence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java does not put the java class file name in `args[]`, `args[]` contains only parameters to pass as `main()` function arguments, so in your example this condition `args.length != 2` checks if exactly two arguments are passed to the `main()` function while executing the commands:

- `javac classFile.java` => To compile the java file.
- `java classFile one two` => Execute the `main()` function using 'one' and 'two' as arguments.

Comment: HI Brahim Khouy thank you for your explanation. It is clear now.